# deluge doesn't start up on boot - how do I diagnose this problem?

Tags: deluge

I installed deluge and configured it to startup webgui using this tutorial:

http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Install-the-software/Install-Deluge-Headless.html

But it doesn't work! It just worked on first reboot, after that I need to start it manually everytime.

I believe there is something wrong with startup script.

But I have no idea how to diagnose this problem, where should I see logs of what is going wrong? or in general how to deal with this kind of problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, you have process deluge started, but no icon in tray?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu)? It's the original guide that is linked at the end of the article.

Comment: Extender: it's a server. no gui.

Nistorm: yes I read that, and actually used original script cause it looks more up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved issue by simply removing deluge, and reinstalling.

```
sudo apt-get --purge deluge-webui deluge
sudo apt-get install deluge deluge-webui
```